# Exact value of Integral

Tags: integration

I want to solve the following integral exactly
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\cos(t^2)}{1-2a\cos(t)+a^2}dt,\quad -1<a<1.
\end{align*}
I tried different methods but it ends up with Fresnel integrals. Any suggestion or method?

Comment: $a$ lies between $-1$ and $ 1$. i.e., $-1<a<1 $.

Comment: Is the exponent in the numerator on the cosine or on the argument?

Comment: Due to the [Poisson kernel][1] we have:

$$ \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\cos(t^2)}{1-2a\cos t+a^2}\,dt = \frac{1}{1-a^2}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}a^{|n|}\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos(\theta^2)e^{in\theta}\,d\theta \tag{1}$$
and if we expand $\cos(\theta^2)$ as a Fourier series we certainly end with a series whose terms depend on Fresnel integrals. 

  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel

Comment: Thanks....I read this link.......:)